# Return a value from a specific row in a table using DAX or PowerQuery in PowerBi

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple table that has two columns and numerous rows that I pulled into PowerBi desktop.  I want to create two measures, the first to retrieve the value from row 1 column 1 of the table and the second to retrieve the value from row 2 of column 2.  What DAX expression can I use OR is there something I can do in PowerQuery?  Thank you!

Example of table:

```
Column1   |  Column2
----------------------
Date         Country
Price        Close Time
Manager      Customer
```

Measure 1 needs to return: [Date]   Measure 2 needs to return: [Close Time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you are going with this, but if your Columns are named as they are in your example, then (in Power Query M code):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Raptor"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

    #"Row1 Column1" = #"Changed Type"[Column1]{0},
    #"Row2 Column2" = #"Changed Type"[Column2]{1}
in
    {#"Row1 Column1",#"Row2 Column2"}
```

returns a 2 element list with those values

If you don't know the column names, then you can use something like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Raptor"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

    x = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type"),
    r1c1 = x{0}{0},
    r2c2 = x{1}{1}
in 
    {r1c1,r2c2}
```

Both of the above =>
[image]

Comment: Great idea!  Let me ask you this, I am pulling the table in from a web source so the data will change daily, by using the M Code, it would automatically refresh with the PBi report would it??

Comment: @ZRaptor Probably in PBi you would select Transform, and then add the code to your query.

Comment: @Ron_Rosenfeld I don't see anywhere in the transform tab to add M code, just R and Python.  Maybe I am missing something?  Or your just saying adding it to the code for the table itself??

Comment: @ZRaptor Open Advanced Editor. That is all MCode. That is the language of Power Query.